# Maven cannot compile Spring Security demo project

Tags: maven, spring-security

I have a Maven demo project for which I use some Spring Security features.

I could import the project fine into Eclipse STS and the editor shows no error related to dependencies.

But a Maven command to compile on the command line fails.

I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project learnintouch-web: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/learnintouch-web/src/main/java/com/thalasoft/learnintouch/web/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java:[7,78] package org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders does not exist
[ERROR] /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/learnintouch-web/src/main/java/com/thalasoft/learnintouch/web/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java:[8,67] package org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders does not exist
[ERROR] /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/learnintouch-web/src/main/java/com/thalasoft/learnintouch/web/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java:[9,72] package org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration does not exist
[ERROR] /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/learnintouch-web/src/main/java/com/thalasoft/learnintouch/web/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java:[10,72] package org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration does not exist
[ERROR] /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/learnintouch-web/src/main/java/com/thalasoft/learnintouch/web/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java:[19,47] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
[ERROR] /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/learnintouch-web/src/main/java/com/thalasoft/learnintouch/web/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java:[15,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class EnableWebSecurity
[ERROR] /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/learnintouch-web/src/main/java/com/thalasoft/learnintouch/web/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java:[25,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AuthenticationManagerBuilder
[ERROR] location: class com.thalasoft.learnintouch.web.config.WebSecurityConfiguration
[ERROR] /home/stephane/dev/java/projects/learnintouch-web/src/main/java/com/thalasoft/learnintouch/web/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java:[24,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Here is in the pom.xml the Spring Security dependencies:

```
<org.springframework.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I resolved this by removing this line from `pom.xml` on the `spring-security-config` artifact:

```
   <scope>runtime</scope>
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to add spring security library manually.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I could solve this by adding the latest possible compatible versions of **Spring framework**.version and **Spring Security**.version.

Ex:

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springsecurity.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version> 
</properties>
```

Also in the dependencies, I added the below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Now it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

It seems version conflict problem.
I faced same problem and could solve it by changing spring-security version from 3.1.7 to 3.2.4.
Hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I overhauled the dependencies and the build now passes. There was some conflict between Spring dependencies.

Comment: You could have been more specific and detailed - this is barely helpful.

Comment: What does "overhauled the dependencies" entail exactly? What conflict was there between Spring dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue going through some Spring Security tutorials. This is due to versioning conflicts.

Update your POM to remove the version info for all the Spring dependencies. Then throw in the spring-framework-bom to handle your versioning and it should work.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: That smells fishy

Answer (score 0):

in my case this error was caused by version conflict

had java 8 maven app , changed version to java7 and made mvn eclipse:eclipse
from cmd it was running but from eclipse giving error: 
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter cannot be resolved to a type

after project was showing all jars and work was not easy
security jars were not shown 
was giving error : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter cannot be resolved to a type

right click 
from menu choose: configure -> convert to maven project
after right click project and choose properties->java build path : 
check for java version ,remove incorrect java version
with button [add library] change to ide's java version
still in properties window choose:  java compiler
compiler compliance level group 
change to ide's java version
where it is showing incorrect version

that is it

Answer (score 0):

If you have spring boo project add following dependency ,Seems like Spring security jar is missing

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```