# org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding don't exist in maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-security

I had seen [Maven cannot compile Spring Security demo project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259033/maven-cannot-compile-spring-security-demo-project). But my problem don't solve.

The problem is occur in following to code:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

java code(import):

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder;
```

run in `mvn compile`:

```
package org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding does not exist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are deprecated. You may try the replacement:

```
org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder
```

More details are here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.html

Answer (score 8):

`org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` is also deprecated so we can go for `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder` which can be used for different types of algorithm by default it uses bcrypt but supports ldap,MD4, MD5, noop,pbkdf2,scrypt,SHA-1,SHA-256,sha256.

Comment: This is the correct answer, not the selected one below.